# JLabels not in correct coordinates when in my scroll panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, jscrollpane

I was experimenting with scrollable JPanels and I found a problem when placing my JLabels. In the code bellow I tried to have 2 labels in my panel one below another using x and y coordinates. I am not sure why they are being placed right next to each other, and always in the center of the panel.

My Code:

```
public class ScrollTest extends JFrame {
    //GUI Items
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 750, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel title, description;

    public ScrollTest(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setOpaque(true);

        //JLabels
        title = new JLabel("Title");
        title.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 30));
        title.setBounds(40, 50, 500, 40);
        panel.add(title);

        description = new JLabel("Description:");
        description.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        description.setBounds(40, 90, 500, 40);
        panel.add(description);

        add(new JScrollPane(panel));
        setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. If you place a panel in Java a layout-manager kicks in. Per default FlowLayout is used but you can try others. Just use panel.setlayout(<your desired layoutmanager>); 
If you still want to use a direct positioning of your elements you can use Null Layout. But beware: it is not appreciated in the Java-Community to work around the common layout-managers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are displaying just two `JLabel`s, I think a single column [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) is appropriate. Also note that you don't have to write a class that extends `JFrame`. In the beginning, all the *Swing* sample code did this but it is not required. And you don't have to build your GUI in the constructor of your class.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class ScrollTest {
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 750, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;

    private void showGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Title", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        title.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 30));
        panel.add(title);
        JLabel description = new JLabel("Description:");
        description.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        panel.add(description);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(panel));
        frame.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new ScrollTest().showGui());
    }
}
```

This is how it looks.

[image: screen capture of running app]

Because you set the size of the `JFrame` to a large size, there are no scrollbars visible. Refer to the *javadoc* for the `JScrollPane` [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane-java.awt.Component-int-int-).